# Graphically laying out wx app

Tags: code-generation, wxwidgets

Being really new to wx, I'm wondering if there is an IDE (especially for Linux) which would help me lay out a frame or dialog or whatever just to help me see what I'm doing.  That means also creating the code for those changes.

I remember way back when using resource compilers for OS/2 and Windows that produced binaries that would then create the window, and was hoping for something similar (though obviously not binary if wx doesn't support that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [wxFormBuilder](http://www.wxformbuilder.org). It is written in wxWidgets, so it works on Linux quite well. It can generate C++ code or XRC files. Make sure you understand its philosophy, and use it like this:

- generate C++ code for the GUI
- don't edit the code wxFormBuilder generated, but create new files
- in new files, derive new classes from the classes it generated
- implement event handlers in you own class (wxFB creates virtual function for each event handler you wish to use)

I usually name the wxFormBuilder generated classes/files like, for example, MainFrameGUI, and one with implementation (derived one in which I write all my code) would be just MainFrame. This enables you to change the visual layout and regenerate C++ files from wxFB at any time without overwriting your code.

Answer (score 1):

[DialogBlocks](http://www.anthemion.co.uk/dialogblocks/) works quite well for me, although sometimes you need to edit the code to fix errors manually. It has a property editor that seems advanced enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just another options is [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/). It does not have the that much features as the others mentioned seem to have, but it works just good enough for me to not daring to switch.

Comment: I used to use wxGlade before. It was good enough while wxFormBuilder was still in development. But now that it is stable I find wxFB much better. It does not crash, supports event handling much better and is much more easier to use custom classes.

Comment: wxGlade crashes a lot for me (unexpectedly closes). It also doesn't support my, admittedly weird, multi-monitor setup properly. Will try the FormBuilder...

Answer (score 1):

I use Code::Blocks IDE from http://www.codeblocks.org which has
   - built-in GUI editor
   - Cross compilable, so you can use it under Linux, OSX and Windows.

But I still use wxFormBuilder with it instead of built-in wxSmith editor. But they are compatible with internal wxSmith.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you've got "wx-devcpp" which is Blodsheed Dev C++ with some addons providing what you looking for

Here is project page
http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/