# What is the preferred method for creating a wxWidget application: using a GUI tool or procedurally in code?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, gui-designer

I use wxWidgets to create test tools at work.  I have always created the GUI by creating the widgets in code.  I haven't tried any of the tools available that help to do this.  How do other users of wxWidgets typically create their interface?  If you use a tool, which tool do you use?  If you use a tool, what advantages and disadvantages do you think there are for using that tool?

Comment: Here's a related question but geared towards Qt - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623692/handcode-gui-or-use-gui-designer-tool

Comment: Here's another question that has an answer that recommends wxFormBuilder.  It also mentions how to modify the GUI without having to rewrite event handlers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224547/graphically-laying-out-wx-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/) for two reasons:

1. It's cross-platform and I needed something that would work on Linux.
2. I'm new to wxWidgets and I didn't want to spend lots of time futzing about with building the GUI.

I think it works quite well, and being familiar with similar GUI building tools (Borland C++ Builder, Jigloo for Java, Delphi) I found it easy to use.

If you stick with the paradigm of using wxFormBuilder to generate base classes, and then you make a class that inherits to layer your application specific logic on top, absolutely not hand-editing the C++ code wxFormBuilder generates, then it works well and you can easily update and modify your GUIs in wxFormBuilder again (and again...).

*Advantages:*

- Can generate your base GUIs quite quickly, in a visual manner, without having to constantly look up the documentation.
- Don't have to do as many code/compile/run cycles just to make sure your GUI is looking like what you expected.
- The base class/derived class paradigm can make a reasonably clean separation of your GUI and business logic code.

*Potential Disadvantages*

- *Disclaimer:* I've only used wxWidgets to create very simple, straight-forward GUIs, so haven't really pushed the tool to any limits.
- Potentially the base class/derived class paradigm could sometimes get in your way if you are doing something too sophisticated with your GUI (OTOH that could indicate that you may need to re-think your approach.)
- I had a situation where I needed a menu item when compiled for one operating system, but not when compiled for another.  There is no logic in wxFormBuilder to support this. I ended up taking the short-cut of always creating the menu item and then having my derived class make it invisible if it was the wrong OS (not ideal.)

That's about it, I think.

Answer (score 3):

What I find is that I often build the first cut at a GUI using a tool, and when it seems to be converging on the "final" form, I start to recode/refactor by hand.

Some of this depends on the tools, though, too.  I'm not a big wxWidget fan.

Comment: That seems to be a good compromise. Some things like proper platform-specific control spacing are beyond the capabilities of GUI design tools (at least I know of none able to do a good job).

Comment: Yeah, and the "round trip engineering" aspects really never seem to work.  Eventually you have to hack the code by hand, and hen God help the tool.

Answer (score 1):

You know, it depends.
E.g. if I need some standard behaviour, I usually use DialogBlocks for GUI because it is the fastest way.
If I need custom behaviour (e.g. my current project is cross-platform media manager whose GUI supports skins) then I do all GUI-relates things in code.
As for custom controls:

- If a control does some project-specific thing, then I create it in DialogBlocks using the same project file (with other forms and dialogs used in this project)
- If my control should be reusable (general-purpose control) then I create a separate project for it and create a keleton in DialogBlocks - add empty event handlers and class variables if possible, then write logic manually in Visual Studio.

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using [XRC/XRS files](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_xrcoverview.html).

Though I must admit I haven't bothered to do so myself. Just generating static GUI code using wxFormBuilder (which has XRC support, btw) has been enough for all my (small-scale) GUI designs.